# Enable syntax highlight for file extension contained somewhere in filename

Tags: vim, syntax, file-extension

How can I overwrite default vim file extension to syntax rules to work if filename contains `.extension` anywhere in filename?

For file named `file.html.jinja2` I want vim to use HTML syntax.

I just want to avoid making multiple `au` for each filetype.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an autocommand with `*` wildcards, for example:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWinEnter *.html* setf html
```

The `BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWinEnter` events ensure that the filetype is detected if the file is loaded or created. You may need to add more events, depending on your editing workflow.

Comment: I know that already. "I just want to avoid making multiple au for each filetype."
Are you saying there is no workaround?

Comment: The original HTML filetype detection is in the `filetype.vim` file that ships with Vim and should not be edited. So, you already need to define another `:au`. No way around it.